# How can I extend Calendar on Android?

Tags: android

I mean, is there any way to

- add more functionality
- add/remove events
- synchronize with other then Google calendars/formats (authorized)

Answer (score 2):

There is a content provider available for Calendar entries: `android.provider.Calendar.CONTENT_URI` ([see brief documentation here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)).

Though, I'd consider using the [Google Calendar Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/). You should be able to authenticate the user using [AccountManager#getAuthToken](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) and edit calendar entries in very rich and well-documented ways.